# About MFC C++ Polymorphism

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, polymorphism

I'm getting stuck with MFC C++ polymorphism, here's my problem:

I have a class, let's say A, that implements a lot of useful stuff, but every object I need to instantiate from it, requires a little customization, so I decided to derive each of my classes (i.g.: A1, A2... ).
Now, the initialization of these objects require some operations that are the same for ALL subclasses, so I've build a static method that does this task and here comes the problem:

```
void CFastInit::FastGrid( const CStatic &stPosition, A *pGrid, UINT nID, CWnd *pWnd )
{
    stPosition.GetClientRect( rctGriPos );
    stPosition.MapWindowPoints( pWnd, rctGriPos );
    pGrid->Create( WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rctGriPos, pWnd, nID );
    pGrid->SetWholeRowSel();
}
```

From the Debugger I can see that pGrid is of right type ( A1, A2... ), but the call:

```
pGrid->Create(
```

is done to A::Create and not to A1::Create or A2::Create. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Is `Create()` a `virtual` function?

Comment: Is Create a static method? If so, this is an expected behavior, since static method is bound to the particular class (A in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have a static function `FastGrid()`. Note that this function is shared by *all* objects of the base class, *and* all objects of any class derived from base.

In this function, you are getting a pointer to the base class as a parameter:  `A *pGrid`, and then make a function call on that pointer: `pGrid->Create()`.

Now, if `pGrid` points on a *derived* class object, you need the `Create()` function to be `virtual`, if you want to have polymorphism. If it is not virtual, the `Create()` function of a base class will always get called.

Probably you want something like this:

```
class base
{
public:
    static void foo( base * ptr)
    {
        ptr->bar();
    }
    virtual void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "base class bar() call" << std::endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
    virtual void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "derived class bar() call" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    base::foo( new derived() );
}
```

Output:

```
derived class bar() call
```

If you remove the `virtual` keyword, the output will be

```
base class bar() call
```

and that's what you have now. Also note that the static function in my example could be also called like this: `derived::foo( new derived() );`, that would not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's because pGrid is given with type "A". You could use typechecking and cast it to force it to use the method you want.

Comment: I will try to help more after you answer some of the other posters questions (it will help clear up things for me as well)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add virtual keyword may be the root cause in your case, however, if you called a instance method from the ctor, the virtual function doesn't work either, as the compiler will ensure the virtual table pointer in the scope of ctor of base class belongs to base class and so it is with the derived class.

And, beside of the virtual function, the template also could be used to reach a similar effects as you would see lots of examples in ATL